# Search one file to see if it contains information from another file

Tags: files, scripting

I have two files. The first is `unip.txt` and the second is `ipex.txt` and each file contains IP addresses.

`unip.txt`:

```
49.235.113.205
50.115.166.136
51.15.70.104
51.15.87.74
51.15.134.103
146.148.13.9
148.70.23.131
148.72.212.161
148.216.29.46
149.56.141.193
```

`ipex.txt`:

```
51.15.134.103
148.70.23.131
151.141.0.0
97.89.32.238
```

I'm trying to figure out how to basically search the `unip.txt` file to see if it contains any IP from the `ipex.txt` file. I imagine that it would be a loop to search through every line, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is built into `grep`. Use the `-f` option:

```
grep -Fx -f ipex.txt unip.txt
```

That prints all matches. If you are only interested in a yes/no answer, use the `-q` option ("quiet"):

```
if grep -Fxq -x -f ipex.txt unip.txt; then
    echo unip.txt contains IP addresses from ipex.txt
else
    echo "unip.txt doesn't contain IP addresses from ipex.txt"
fi
```

Why `-F`? By default, grep interprets the lines in `ipex.txt` as regular expressions, and the dots in those lines have the meaning of "any character". This can (and likely will) lead to false matches. `-F` ensures that constant strings, not regular expressions, are matched.

Why `-x`? It ensures that IP addresses are matched to whole lines in `unip.txt`, thereby preventing partial matches, e.g. preventing `49.235.113.20` from matching an address `49.235.113.205`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach I like for this type of problem is the `comm` command. It's useful to compare two files and determine (1) the lines found *only* in file1, (2) the lines found *only* in file2, and (3) the lines found in *both* files. The only downsides are that both input files need to be sorted, and it matches exact lines (i.e., doesn't look for substrings within a line).

I saved your examples as `unip.txt` and `ipex.txt`, sorted them using `sort`, then ran `comm unip.txt ipex.txt`. The output:

```
146.148.13.9
148.216.29.46
        148.70.23.131
148.72.212.161
149.56.141.193
    151.141.0.0
49.235.113.205
50.115.166.136
        51.15.134.103
51.15.70.104
51.15.87.74
    97.89.32.238
```

The output has three tab-delimited columns, corresponding to points (1), (2), and (3) that I made above. You can suppress the output of a column like so: `comm -1 unip.txt ipex.txt`. That command would *not* print the first column.

So, overall, to answer your question you need to sort your input files and then run `comm -12 unip.txt ipex.txt`, which will suppress the first two columns of output and then print the lines found in both files:

```
148.70.23.131
51.15.134.103
```

Hope this helps!